# Tkinter: How do you place a text field that you can update at whim?

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, nameerror

I want to be able to manipulate an integer that will be displayed in real-time in the Tk window.

I tried:

```
xp = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=xp).pack()
xp.set(0)
```

and then later, I tried:

```
xp.set(xp+1)
```

But it failed badly on that line, with the message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
File "/usr/lib/.../Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "rpg.py", line 26, in fight
  xp.set(xp+1)
NameError: global name 'xp' is not defined
```

I want to be able to increment the "xp" value, and it show up in real-time in the window. I also want to be able to manipulate "xp" as an integer, with multiplication and exponents and the such.

So if you can point out what I am doing incorrectly then I would be glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like the scope of the `xp` variable in the first snippet does not include the second snippet. This means that they're really different variables (that happen to have a very similar name) and so the second snippet is being run without the handle to the `StringVar` accessible, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the same class but a different function. How do I declare the variable so that it may be used in more than one function in a class?

Comment: @thatbennyguy you can assign the variable to "self", that way you can access it from anywhere in the class. Just replace "xp" with "self.xp".

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html and on the basis of what I remember (as a non-Python programmer, so beware!) replace `xp` with `self.__xp`.